# How to set the height of an input (text) field in CSS?

Tags: html, css, textfield

Sorry for this question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.
I have CSS code that should set the height of my text box. I am using VS2010 Express for Windows phone, coding in HTML/CSS/Javascript/C#.

**HTML**

```
<input class="heighttext" type="text" id="name">
```

**CSS**

```
.heighttext{
  height:30px
}
```

I can set the height to anything I like, but the text box will stay the same!
Please help, or at least send me a link that can!

Comment: seems a semicolon is missing in your css code

Comment: Well, [it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vMwYD/). @Kaipa: the semi-colon for the *last* CSS rule is optional.

Comment: right, got it now. It is optional!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try with `padding` and `line-height` -

```
input[type="text"]{ padding: 20px 10px; line-height: 28px; }
```

Comment: @Dipkas this worked very well for me!, but may i ask you why the padding have 2 properties? and which one should i change to get it a bit smaller? you really helped me out!

Comment: @Arrie This is a short hand to padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px; /*top right bottom left*/ and with two values padding: 20px 10px; /* top-bottom left-right*/... hope this is clear :)

Comment: He wanted a height of 30px.  How does a top/bottom padding of 20 plus a line height of 28 get to a total height of 30?

Comment: I also don't get how this is the answer. Wouldn't this lead to a height of 2 * 20 + 28?

Answer (score 7):

Form controls are notoriously difficult to style cross-platform/browser. Some browsers will honor a CSS `height` rule, some won't.

You can try `line-height` (may need `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`) or `top` and `bottom padding` also. If none of those work, that's pretty much it - use a graphic, position the `input` in the center and set `border:none;` so it *looks* like the form control is big but it actually isn't...

Answer (score 4):

You should use font-size for controlling the height, it is widely supported amongst browsers.
And in order to add spacing, you should use padding.
Forexample,

```
.inputField{
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: `font-size` is only relevant when you want to increase the font size of the input. Sometimes you don't want that side effect.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use height property in input field.

Example:

```
.heighttext{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 10px;
    line-height:140%;
}
```

Always use **padding** and **line-height** css property. Its work perfect for all mobile device and all browser.

Answer (score 2):

> The best way to do this is:

```
input.heighttext{
  padding: 20px 10px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use this style code

```
.heighttext{
 float:right;
 height:30px;
 width:70px;
 }
```