# Extra space below text in input filed; content height does not equal to "font-size" or "line-height"

Tags: html, css

I want the total height of input field will equal to sum of:

- Top and bottom borders
- Top and bottom paddings
- Line height

The solutions from question [How to set the height of an input (text) field in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893205/how-to-set-the-height-of-an-input-text-field-in-css) does not work: the space between top and bottom paddings of input field does not equal to `line-height`.

In below example, `font-size` and `line-height` are `14px`, but contents height is `16px`. Maybe it depends on browser, so I created the screenshot for newest Chrome.

[image]

```css
#input {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 14px;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
  
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="test">
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more of what you are expecting here

Comment: you can use only height attribute

Comment: @SalunkeAkash, O'K, I'll edit. Sorry for unclear question.

Comment: @SalunkeAkash, Understood, but why I can not size the height by line-height, paddings and border?

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41336508/11926876 it will help you understand how this works

Comment: @SalunkeAkash, I'll check. Thank you for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#input {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 14px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
  
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="test">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is interpretation "you should not setup paddings for input fields" correct?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is to explicitly set the content height of the element to `1lh`.

The CSS `lh` unit refers to the line-height of the element, so if the line-height of the element is `14px`, then setting `height: 1lh` on the element means the input element's total height should be exactly `14px`.

Note that if you are using `box-sizing: border-box` on all your elements, you will need to do the math in a `calc` expression:

```
#input {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: calc(1lh + 20px + 2px); /* <-- [line-height] + [vertical padding] + [vertical border-width] */

 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 14px;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
  
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
```

However, if you are using `box-sizing: content-box` on all your elements, you can just directly set the height to `1lh`:

```
#input {
 box-sizing: content-box;
 height: 1lh;

 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 14px;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
  
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here seems to be that no matter what you set as a CSS `line-height` of a text `input`, the effective value cannot be smaller than `16px` (or, presumably, default font size of the user agent). Unlike other non-replaced elements, like `span`, for example, which happily accepts even zero `line-height`.

Sandbox, try different values and their outcomes:

```js
i.oninput();
s.oninput();
```

```html
Input: <input id=i
 oninput="
  style.lineHeight=value;
  out1.value=getComputedStyle(this).lineHeight
 "
 value="10px"
>
Computed lh: <output id=out1></output>

<hr>

Span: <span id=s
 contenteditable
 style="border: inset; min-width: 5em; display: inline-block;"
 oninput="
  this.style.lineHeight=this.textContent;
  out2.value=getComputedStyle(this).lineHeight
 "
>10px</span>
Computed lh: <output id=out2></output>
```

Renders [image: input set to 10px line height produces 16px lh, span set to 10px line-height produces 10px lh] in Firefox. Chrome apparently either lies in `computedStyle.lineHeight` reading, or uses some other mechanism for keeping the minimal optical height of the text input. (How amusing.)